# Approximation error of symmetric nonnegative matrix factorization (SNMF)

Tags: matrices, matrix-decomposition, symmetric-matrices

I am trying to approximate a square symmetric nonnegative matrix $A \in \mathbb{R_+}^{n \times n}$ using the following matrix factorization

$$A \approx \hat{A} = P P^T$$

with $P \in \mathbb{R_+}^{n \times r}$ and $r << n$.

There are some novel papers on this factorization, e.g. [Efficient and Non-Convex Coordinate Descent for Symmetric Nonnegative Matrix Factorization](https://arxiv.org/abs/1509.01404) with code available. I tried to implement the $\alpha$-SNMF and $\beta$-SNMF Newton like methods from [Symmetric Nonnegative Matrix Factorization:
Algorithms and Applications to Probabilistic
Clustering](http://ieeexplore.ieee.org/stamp/stamp.jsp?arnumber=6061964). But the errors in approximation are around 30%, which seems very high to me. Are there no methods in order to achieve an approximation with an error less than that?